# Symbolic derivatives with vectors and matrices

Tags: matrix, symbolic, vector, vector-calculus

I'm currently trying to solve some problems using symbolic vectors and matrices of arbitrary size. However, I have some problems with understanding and verifying the results:

I defined the vectors as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15335/8517)

```
$Assumptions = { Element[x, Matrices[{m, 1}, Reals]], 
   Element[a, Matrices[{m, 1}, Reals]] };
```

Now I'm trying to compute the gradient (`m x 1` matrix) and hessian (`m x m` matrix) of the function f

```
f[x_, a_] := Dot[a, x]^2
```

using

```
In[144]:= D[f[x, a], x]
Out[144]= 2 a.1 a.x

In[143]:= D[f[x, a], x, Transpose[x]]
Out[143]= 0
```

What does `a.1` mean? is it just `a` or more like `sum[a]` ? And why does the second term for the hessian just give `0`? Shouldn't it be something like `2*a*Transpose[a]` ?

Comment: Derivatives for symbolic tensors are not supported. You would either have to write out components explicitly (which you can't if you don't know `m`), or use  packages that can do this. I would look at NCAlgebra and see if it has support for derivatives. http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/DOWNLOAD2010/DOCUMENTATION/html/NCBIGDOCch4.html

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks a lot (also for the sad news ;-) ). I had a look at NCAlgebra but find it very hard to learn/understand the syntax. Do you know further alternatives (even commercial if need be)?

Comment: No, I am not very familiar with these kinds of packages. Try searching on http://packagedata.net/

Comment: Just wondering if you ever found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @oracle3001 unfortunately no. I suppose its currently not possible with mathematica.