# How to handle functions with varying number of arguments

Tags: functions, function-construction, arguments

Suppose I have a function that depends on variables $x_1, ... , x_n$.
For concreteness I may have $f(x) = v \cdot x$, with $v$ a certain vector.

Now I want to do certain operation with this function, for example to compute its gradient.

I would like to write a mathematica code that works for any n. Thus, I cannot write something like

```
f[x1_,...,xn_]:= (any clever way to write v . x);
```

because that would not work for another n: I have to manually write the new simbols x1,...,xn'.

Also, the following would not work:

```
f[x_]:= v . x;
```

because then I would not be able to use Derivative, as f is now a function of a single argument (a list), and it is impossible to get the derivative with respect to x[[2]] say. (Right?)

What is the best design to work with this kind of problems?

Comment: `ClearAll[f]; f[x__] := v.{x}`?

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135150)

Comment: Of course Mathematica functions *can* have an arbitrary number of arguments. But why not just let the function take a list, which is treated as a single argument?  `f[list_List]:=Total[list]`.  Using the multi-argument notation, this would be `f[x___]:=Total[{x}]`.  Here I put `x` between curly braces again to make a list out of it.  So it's really the same thing as a function taking a list-argument.  The difference is only notation, nothing else. This should make it easier for you to think about the problem.

Comment: But how would you compute the derivative with respect to the i-th argument?

Comment: `D` was enhanced in V11.1 to help with this sort of problem. Take a look at this [Wolfram Blog article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/05/25/new-in-the-wolfram-language-enhanced-derivatives/)